# Keyboard Shortcut: How to move cursor to the next capital letter of word written in camelCase in macOS & Xcode

Tags: macos, xcode

I'm able to move the cursor using <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>) to the end of a word. However, if the word is camelCase, I want to move the cursor to the next capital letter.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> (<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>).

Comment: Not working, I'm on IDE Xcode, macOS Mojave. Is there a specific settings I can look at?

Comment: It's in the Xcode Preferences -> Key Bindings -> Move Subword Forward/Backward. It's probably cancelled by the System keybinding for changing the current desktop.